# String cannot be converted to CloudEvents

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, cloudevents

I am new to Kafka and trying to do some testing with a producer/consumer pair.

I have a producer that looks like the below code.

```
String key = "key1";
    String message = "{}"; // has valid json
    CloudEventBuilder ceb = new CloudEventBuilder().withId("123").withSource(xxxxxxxx)
        .withType("test").withData(message.getBytes());

    topicPublisher.publish(key, ceb.build());
```

On my consumer side, I am trying to retrieve the message.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"quickstart-events"},groupId = "group1")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, CloudEvent> cloudEventRecord) {
    eventHandler.processEvent(cloudEventRecord);
    System.out.println("received: "+ " key->"+ cloudEventRecord.key() + " value-> "+cloudEventRecord.value().getId());
  }
```

An error is thrown at this line.

```
cloudEventRecord.value().getId()
```

This is the reason:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
> cast to io.cloudevents.CloudEvent

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-java/issues/196) may have something useful for you.

Comment: Please share your Spring properties where you've set `value.deserializer` to something other than StringDeserializer

Comment: @ryyker That [shouldn't be necessary with Kafka](https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-java/blob/master/kafka/src/main/java/io/cloudevents/kafka/CloudEventMessageDeserializer.java)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - LOL, Mine was a complete shot in the dark.   But thanks for linking the small example code.  Kafka looks powerful.

Comment: @ryyker It's not example code. Kafka always stores bytes. Spring-Kafka library defaults to consume as Strings, I believe, so that needs overwritten with the linked class.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all, Found that I did not use the right deserializer. I does not figure in the code above.